# How to run shell script from MacBook Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, command-line, touch-bar

I have a simple shell script command like this which can be run via automator or workflow:

```
cd /Users/myuser/Documents/Code-Files/scripts/; 
/usr/local/bin/node code_upload.js
```

I'd like to add this as a Quick Action to the MacBook's Touch Bar, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!